# ¿Pista de audio WAV en JAVA al presionar un botón?

Tags: java

Buen día a todos los del foro, necesito de su apreciable ayuda para adaptar el siguiente código que reproduce audio al iniciar la aplicación y que vez de eso solo se reproduzca una pista diferente para cada botón, de antemano agradezco cualquier apoyo.
El código es el siguiente:

```
 import com.panamahitek.ArduinoException;
 import com.panamahitek.PanamaHitek_Arduino;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import jssc.SerialPortException;
 import java.io.*;
 import sun.audio.*;


public class JavaTX extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//Se crea la instancia de la librería PanamaHitek_Arduino
PanamaHitek_Arduino ino = new PanamaHitek_Arduino();
public JavaTX() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        //Se inicia la comunicación con el Puerto Serie
        ino.arduinoTX("COM4", 9600);
    } catch (ArduinoException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaTX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Arduino Serial Switch | Panama Hitek");

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("Encender");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("Apagar");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {
        ino.sendData("1");
    } catch (ArduinoException | SerialPortException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaTX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //Se hace el envío del String "0"
    try {
        ino.sendData("0");
    } catch (ArduinoException | SerialPortException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaTX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                        

public static void main(String args[])  throws Exception  {
    String sonido1 = "C:/users/jesus/desktop/sonido/NombreAudio.wav";
    String sonido2 = "C:/users/jesus/desktop/sonido/NombreAudio.wav";

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sonido1);
    InputStream in2 = new FileInputStream(sonido2);
    AudioStream audio1 = new AudioStream(in);
       AudioStream audio2 = new AudioStream(in2);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audio1);

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JavaTX().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
// End of variables declaration                   
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si ese código funciona y los botones son los que se muestran entonces simplemente copia y pega el código que reproduce el sonido desde el "main" a cada uno de los botones, quedaría algo así en el botón 1:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {
         ino.sendData("1");

         //Código Sonido 1
         String sonido1 = "C:/users/jesus/desktop/sonido/NombreAudio.wav";    
         InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sonido1);    
         AudioStream audio1 = new AudioStream(in);
         AudioPlayer.player.start(audio1);

    } catch (ArduinoException | SerialPortException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(JavaTX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

 }
```

Y haces lo mismo con el botón 2 lo único es que cambias el nombre del archivo a reproducir. Y recuerda borrar o comentar el código del "main" que reproduce el sonido al iniciar.

Para detener el Audio debes declarar el AudioStream (audio1 y 2) fuera de los botones porque de la forma como están son de acceso local, para que así puedas tener acceso en cualquier sitio que lo necesites. Para ello modifica el código y declara debajo de:

```
 PanamaHitek_Arduino ino = new PanamaHitek_Arduino();
 //Declara aquí los AudioStream
 AudioStream audio1;
 AudioStream audio2;
```

Para luego modificar e instanciar en cada botón los audios y quedaría así:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

     try {
          ino.sendData("1");

          //Código Sonido 1
          String sonido1 = "C:/users/jesus/desktop/sonido/NombreAudio.wav";    
          InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sonido1);
          //Aquí instancias el AudioStream    
          audio1 = new AudioStream(in);
          AudioPlayer.player.start(audio1);

     } catch (ArduinoException | SerialPortException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaTX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }

  }
```

Y para detener el audio creas el botón de detener audio y quedaría algo así:

```
 private void jButtonDetenerAudioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

     try {
          ino.sendData("1");

          //Código Sonido 1
          AudioPlayer.player.stop(audio1);

     } catch (ArduinoException | SerialPortException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaTX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }

  }
```

He aquí la importancia de declarar el AudioStream fuera de los botones para que así puedas tener acceso al audio que esté sonando desde el botón DetenerAudio.

Nota: Tienes que estar pendiente de la excepción (try/catch) si no detiene ve que error te arroja en la excepción.

Bueno espero que te sirva.

Siempre a la orden!!!!

Comment: muchas gracias, le agradezco su ayuda saludos, funciona a la perfección

Comment: molestando con el mismo asunto como podría detener la pista de música con otro botón? por ejemplo al presionar otro botón, se detenga la pista de música , intente crear un método publico para llamarlo en otro botón y que se detenga la pista

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta para detener el audio, saludos!!!.

Comment: Muchas gracias, saludos

Comment: Siempre a la Orden!!!!